# How do I modify multiple range of rows for a newly created Column in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I've been having trouble trying to modify multiple range of rows' values for a newly created column in a dataframe and was hoping to get some help. I apologize if this question has been asked before and would really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.I am a newbie to python coding

So I import a bunch of data from a P&L spreadsheet for multiple companies that consolidate to a total;and clean it before making these said modifications for further analysis:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

dftabulate = lambda df:tabulate(df,headers='keys',tablefmt='psql')
CleanCols = [5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17]
SummaryRows = [0,39,44,58,62,79,87]

VA = pd.read_excel('Columnar BU P&L.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Variance by Co')
VA = VA[98:197]
VA = VA.iloc[:,CleanCols]
VA.columns =  ['Expense','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'All Companies']
VA = VA.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any')
VA = VA.reset_index(drop = True)
VAtcols = VA.columns.drop('Expense')
VA[VAtcols] = VA[VAtcols].astype(int)
VM = VA.iloc[SummaryRows]
VA['Exp Category'] = 'NA'
print(dftabulate(VA.head()))
```

Output looks like this:

```
                                    Expense      A  ...  All Companies  Exp Category
0  General and Administrative Expenses (G&A) -4550  ...         133886            NA
1                             Communications   -17  ...          -4793            NA
2                              Fuel - Travel     0  ...          -1274            NA
3                             Mileage & Auto   449  ...           -251            NA
4                                     Travel     0  ...           1187            NA
```

What I am trying to achieve is to change the newly created Exp Category column to multiple values depending on the row indexes. for example, I'd like to change rows 1:12 as Travel & Entertainment and so on. When I use the below code to create this categorization, it does not throw an error but it wont change the NA assigned values to this column and I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
VA[1:12]['Exp Category'] = 'Travel & Entertainment'
VA[13:18]['Exp Category'] = 'Office Supplies & Expenses'
VA[19:24]['Exp Category'] = 'Professional Fees'
VA[25:28]['Exp Category'] = 'Fees & Assessments'
VA[29:30]['Exp Category'] = 'IT Expense'
VA[31:32]['Exp Category'] = 'Bad Debt Expense'
VA[33:38]['Exp Category'] = 'Misc Expense'
VA[40:43]['Exp Category'] = 'Marketing Expenses'
VA[45:57]['Exp Category'] = 'Payroll & Related Expenses'
VA[59:61]['Exp Category'] = 'Utilities Expenses'
VA[63:69]['Exp Category'] = 'Equip Maint & Rental Expenses'
VA[70:78]['Exp Category'] = 'Mill Expenses'
VA[80:82]['Exp Category'] = 'Taxes'
VA[83:86]['Exp Category'] = 'Insurance'
VA[88:89]['Exp Category'] = 'Incentive Compensation'
VA[89:90]['Exp Category'] = 'Strategic Initiative'
```

Output still looks like this with a caveat message about returning-a-view-verus-a-copy:

```
                                    Expense      A  ...  All Companies  Exp Category
0  General and Administrative Expenses (G&A) -4550  ...         133886            NA
1                             Communications   -17  ...          -4793            NA
2                              Fuel - Travel     0  ...          -1274            NA
3                             Mileage & Auto   449  ...           -251            NA
4                                     Travel     0  ...           1187            NA
```

I tried to look into the "SettingWithCopyWarning" message but despite reading that material I dont understand how to fix it and would really be grateful for any feedback!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `VA['Exp Category'] = ['Travel & Entertainment'] * 12 + ['Office Supplies & Expenses']* 6 +...`

Comment: For more information, see [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Comment: Thank you so much! I did have a little bit of difficulty in implementing this since it was for a lot of rows but I do understand the logic behind this! appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pd.loc might achieve what you're looking for:

**Example DataFrame**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'b': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df

    a   b
0   1   NA
1   2   NA
2   3   NA
3   4   NA
```

**Apply pd.loc to DataFrame**

```
df.loc[0:2, 'b'] = 'Test'
df

    a   b
0   1   Test
1   2   Test
2   3   Test
3   4   NA
```

**Example with your data**

```
# Python indexing starts at 0, so row 1 = position 0
VA.loc[0:11, 'Exp Category'] = 'Travel & Entertainment'
```

Hope this helps!